# proper value assignment from tuple of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, openpyxl

I have this basic question but can't get my head around:

```
prepared_data = ([1, '7303 ', 'product1'], [2, '7304 ', 'product2'], [3, '7534 ', 'product3'], [4, '7652 ', 'product4'])
```

I want to assign these values but can't get how to properly arrange loops:

```
for row_num in range(2, len(prepared_data)+2):
    for index in range(len(prepared_data)):
        wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=1).value = prepared_data[index][0]
        wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=2).value = prepared_data[index][1]
        wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=3).value = prepared_data[index][2]
        wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=4).value = 'John'
```

Program should fill in cells from the second row. But it always overwrites all the values before. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want a single `for` loop, where `row_num` is a function of the index of `prepared_data`. You can make that function implicit by using `enumerate` with an appropriate starting value.

```
for row_num, (some_int, some_str, some_label) in enumerate(prepared_data, start=2):
    wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=1).value = some_int
    wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=2).value = some_str
    wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=3).value = some_label
    wb2_ws1.cell(row=row_num, column=4).value = 'John'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't know that you can loop through both values like that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to have something like:

```
   1|2|3
   7303|7304|7354
   product1|product2|product3
```

But, while your row numbers are increasing, your `index` is resetting in each row so you'll always get the first row.

There are two ways to do this: either you write the columns directly:

```
for col_num, col in enumerate(prepared_data):
   for row_num, value in enumerate(col, 2):
      ws.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num, value=value)
```

Or you use `zip()` on your list to transpose the members so that you can just `append()` to your sheet. This is left as an exercise to the reader!